# call immediate versus call dword near [dword addr]

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, nasm

So recently I've been wanting to call some win32 calls from assembly, and I've been using NASM as my external assembler. I was calling `SendMessage` in my code in the following way:

```
call __imp__SendMessageW@16
```

This was assembled into a relative jump (0xE8 opcode) and the result was an access violation. In the debugger, the computed jump offset seemed to be the correct one (in that `__imp__SendMessageW@16` really did seem to reside there) but nonetheless it did not work. Examining the assembly produced by Visual Studio when I called the function from C++, I noticed that it wasn't a relative immediate jump it was using, but instead (in the language of MASM) a `call dword ptr [__imp__SendMessageW@16]`, corresponding to an 0xFF15 opcode. After some futzing around I figured out that NASM syntax encodes this as `call dword near [dword __imp__SendMessageW@16]`, and making the change my code suddenly worked.

My question is, why does one work and not the other? Is there some relocation of code going on that causes the relative immediate call to jump somewhere unfriendly? I've never been much of an assembly programmer but my impression was always that the two calls should do the same thing and the main difference is that one is position independent and the other is not (assuming that they move the IP to the same place). The relocation of code theory makes sense given that, but then how do you explain the debugger showing the right address?

Also: what's the logic behind the `[]` syntax in this call? The offset is still an immediate (just little endian encoded immediately after 0xFF15), there's no memory access going on here beyond the instruction fetch (I tend to think of `[]` as a dereference outside the context of `lea`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
call dword[__imp__SendMessageW@16]
```

_*imp*_SendMessageW@16 is an address to your imports section that contains the address of the API function. You use the square brackets to deference (call the address STORED by this address)

Comment: Ah, wait a minute then ... `__imp__SendMessageW@16` is a function pointer? So the issue then presumably is that this data resides on a no-execute page and that's why I'm getting an access violation, is that correct?

Comment: So, the follow up question then: what is the logic behind generating this kind of indirection? A little experimentation confirms that I cannot call `_SendMessageW` or `SendMessageW` directly, although the VS debugger recognizes the value of `[dword __imp__SendMessageW@16]` as `SendMessageW`. I know on Linux systems shared libraries index functions through a table, but I thought I remembered reading that Windows does actual relocation, i.e. it maintains a list of offsets in the code and patches it on load. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: It's part of the PE (portable executable) specification. External functions are stored as references in the "idata" section of the EXE then when the EXE is loaded (the DLLs are loading into memory) and the exact location of the APIs are placed as data in those references.

Comment: As usual, Raymond Chen has all the gory details on _why_ things are this way: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/07/27/680250.aspx I suggest reading at least "Rethinking the way DLL exports are resolved for 32-bit Windows" and the two articles that follow it.

Comment: This is a great series of articles, Martin. Thank goodness for Raymond Chen, I swear I always find myself back on his blog when I want to know what's *really* going on.